# How do I route search form to controller method that redirects to /show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I am still new to Rails and trying to tackle something I understand is a little bit higher level. My application needs to accept a code input by a user (a hashed event code **unique** to the event) and then redirect them to that specific event's show page if it is found. If it is not found, it displays an error div.
Instead of throwing an error whenever I test it, like it should, it just points me to a generic /show page. I have pieced this together from about a dozen other Stack posts and tutorials and not a single one has demonstrated exactly the kind of functionality I need. What I need is that when this form submits, it needs to be running something in the controller that is trying to .find that specific object, and if successful runs a redirect to it. When troubleshooting I yanked out that redirect line in my controller and found that it wasn't even running, something else was pointing it to /show. How to I get my form to just ask my method what to do? Is a custom route the right way to go?
Right now, my form looks like this:

```
<h2><br/>Input your event code below<br/></h2>
<p>
<form action="<%= lookup_path(:code) %>" method="get" >
    <%= text_field_tag( :code, nil, class: "input_field") %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit", :name => nil, :class =>"submit_button" %>
</form>
</p>

<div id="errorbar">
    <%= @error_bar %>
</div>`
```

My controller in its entirety is this:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def lookup
        begin
            an_event = Event.where(:event_code =>params[:code])
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            @error_bar = "Code not found"
        end  
    end
end
```

And as far as relevant parts of my routes go:

```
resources :event do
    resources :room
end

get 'event/:event_code' => 'event#lookup', as: :lookup
```

Rake routes:
    `Prefix          Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
   welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                 welcome#index
            root GET    /                                        welcome#index
event_room_index GET    /event/:event_id/room(.:format)          room#index
                 POST   /event/:event_id/room(.:format)          room#create
  new_event_room GET    /event/:event_id/room/new(.:format)      room#new
 edit_event_room GET    /event/:event_id/room/:id/edit(.:format) room#edit
      event_room GET    /event/:event_id/room/:id(.:format)      room#show
                 PATCH  /event/:event_id/room/:id(.:format)      room#update
                 PUT    /event/:event_id/room/:id(.:format)      room#update
                 DELETE /event/:event_id/room/:id(.:format)      room#destroy
     event_index GET    /event(.:format)                         event#index
                 POST   /event(.:format)                         event#create
       new_event GET    /event/new(.:format)                     event#new
      edit_event GET    /event/:id/edit(.:format)                event#edit
           event GET    /event/:id(.:format)                     event#show
                 PATCH  /event/:id(.:format)                     event#update
                 PUT    /event/:id(.:format)                     event#update
                 DELETE /event/:id(.:format)                     event#destroy
          lookup GET    /event/:event_code(.:format)             event#show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

**app/views/events/index.html.erb**

```
<h2><br/>Input your event code below<br/></h2>
<p>
<form action="<%= lookup_path(:code) %>" method="get" >
    <%= text_field_tag( :code, nil, class: "input_field") %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit", :name => nil, :class =>"submit_button" %>
</form>
</p>
```

**app/controllers/event_controller.rb**

```
class EventController < ApplicationController  
  ............  
  def show
    @an_event = Event.where(:event_code =>params[:code])
  end
end
```

**app/views/events/show.html.erb**

```
<% if @an_event.present? %>
  <!-- show event -->
  <%= @an_event.name %>
<% else %>
  <!-- message with error -->
<% end %>
```

have a look at this

**config/routes.rb**

```
event GET    /event/:id(.:format) event#show
.....
lookup GET   /event/:event_code(.:format) event#show
```

The routes are repeated. rename `lookup` to `show`. Remove `lookup` route.

Comment: No luck. if I comment out every single line in the lookup method, it still redirects to "/event/q?code=_thecodeyouputinthetextbox_" and gives my placeholder /show page. Something is wrong in my routes or form that is causing it to always go to that page, ignoring any attempts to redirect or error-check.

Comment: please execute `rake routes` in root project and show the result.

Comment: I seem to be able to strip unique parameters from my events and display them on the show page now. Marking solved, many thanks.